# JHipster node_modules not found

Tags: jhipster, node-modules

I am trying to add dashboard to my JHipster project, but I have a problem with node_modules. I added paths to js scripts in index.html, e.g.: , and when I tried open site I am receiving "Not found". Any ideas? Should I add js file to webpack?

Comment: This is normal, you must not edit the index.html, use webpack. Please read your rpoject's README.md to find how to manage client dependencies.

Comment: Ok, I found, but still have a problem with js. With styles everything is ok, but still my site does not call required js... Any idea?

Comment: It's too vague, please edit your question and share details, code, ..

Comment: So, I added './node_modules/gentelella' to CopyWebpackPlugin, and modified vendor.ts with 'import 'gentelella/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';' and other, I added to vendor.scss all styles and only styles working. js files does not work on my site.

Comment: Nevermind, everything is ok, I mean I can import from node modules js files, but I can not add my own js. I have in vendor.ts: import '/javascript/custom.js'; but webpack can not find this file.